# How do invert my touchpad's orientation?

Tags: 12.04, mouse, touchpad, logitech

I am looking to completely reverse the orientation of an external touchpad (Logitech Wireless Touchpad). This is not just inverting the scrolling: I want to turn it "upside-down" with the click buttons on top and use it as normal.

I found this thread about the Apple Magic Trackpad on Mac but no luck on Linux.

I'm using 12.04 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an available [modification for the Synaptics driver and client](http://cc.oulu.fi/~rantalai/synaptics/) that works nicely for me and for others. There are two drawbacks to mention:

- It involves installing and using development tools such as automake.
- You'll have to repeat it with each upgrade of the Synaptics driver.

There is a [bug report requesting to add the orientation parameter to the stock Synaptics driver and client](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/800064). The bug report is referenced in a broader [idea report involving manual  and automatic orientation of touchpads and touchscreens](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/20789/).